# How to set maximumBatchingWindowInSeconds for AWS SQS in serverless.yml?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have created a serverless.yml file using serverless library. I have created a lambda service and SQS Service. However I am unable set the maximum batching window property in serverless. Currently it is set to 0 and lambda is invoked with single payload.

I have tried using batchWindow property but it doesn't work.

```
  events:
  - sqs: 
      arn: 
        Fn::GetAtt: [ sqsQueue, Arn ]
      batchSize: 4
      batchWindow: 40
```

I have also tried using maximumBatchingWindowInSeconds property but still the value is 0.

```
  events:
  - sqs: 
      arn: 
        Fn::GetAtt: [ sqsQueue, Arn ]
      batchSize: 4
      maximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 40
```

Is there a way we can do it by overriding aws cloudformation resources in serverless?
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/#override-aws-cloudformation-resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct syntax can be found below:

```
events:
      - sqs:
          arn: arn:aws:sqs:region:XXXXXX:myQueue
          batchSize: 10
          maximumBatchingWindow: 60
```

Please make sure that you're using the latest version of the Framework.

Docs: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sqs

Comment: I just tried this. It still does not update the batch window in lambda. Do I need to run sls remove before deploying this?

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of the Framework - you don't have to remove anything, just running a re-deploy should work.

Comment: I guess the problem was the local serverless version. I tried upgrading it and it fixed the issue. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Happy I could help!